# Why am I not using all of the memory in spark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am wondering why my jobs are running very slowly, and it appears to be because I am not using all of the memory available in PySpark.

When I go to the spark UI, and I click on "Executors" I see the following memory used:
[image]

And when I look at my executors I see the following table:
[image]

I am wondering why the "Used" memory is so small compared to the "Total memory.  What can I do to use as much of the memory as possible?

Other information:

- I have a small broadcasted table, but it is only 1MB in size. It should be replicated once per each executor, so I do not imagine it would affect this that much.
- I am using spark managed by yarn
- I am using spark 1.6.1
- Config settings are:

  `spark.executor.memory=45g`

  `spark.executor.cores=2`

  `spark.executor.instances=4`

  `spark.sql.broadcastTimeout = 9000`

  `spark.memory.fraction = 0.6`
- The dataset I am processing has 8397 rows, and 80 partitions.  I am not doing any shuffle operations aside from the repartitioning initially to 80 partitions.

It is the part when I am adding columns that this becomes slow.  All of the parts before that seem to be reasonably fast, when when I try to add a column using a custom udf (using `withColumn`) it seems to be slowing in that part.

There is a similar question here: 
 [How can I tell if my spark job is progressing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43152126/how-can-i-tell-if-my-spark-job-is-progressing)  But my question is more pointed - why does the "Memory Used" show a number so low?

Thanks.

Comment: You've given no details about the dataset youre processing. Hadoop doesn't deal well with small files.

Comment: Editted.  thanks cricket_007 :)

Comment: Don't look at memory used. Look at the input sizes to the executors. How much data do you actually have? Is it really less than 1MB? That should be more alerting than how much the tasks are using. Similarly, why is there 100+ MB shuffle writes  for such small input?

Comment: thanks!  I'm actually using s3 not hadoop.   I know that hadoop doesn't do well with lots of small files because of the overhead memory that it uses on the namenode.  Now, I'd like to understand this from a high level.  So, whatever I see for "Memory Used" - should that be the amount of data in cached memory?  The broadcasted table I am using - yes, it is only 1MB.  The table I'm operating on is about 215 MB when I check the size using http://metricbrew.com/how-to-estimate-rdd-or-dataframe-real-size-in-pyspark/.  What table size do you expect, given the numbers in the screenshot?

Comment: @cricket_007 the 1MB is *only* for the broadcasted table.  how do I check the input sizes to the executors?  When I look at the screenshot I posted above, and sum those up, it does not equal the ~200 MB size of the entire table.

Comment: In the "input" column, that's the data read for the current executor at the time you've rendered the web page. If you refresh, it might update, or new executors could start. I was asking how large is the total data on disk or s3? And if that data is no where near 1G, then why are you trying to give the executors so much memory? Also,  I'm curious if you've attempted to use Spark 2

Comment: In the place in my data processing where spark is seeming making no progress, the table that I'm working on is ~200MB at least the way I've computed the size above, but obviously I use this cluster for other things, so hence the more memory allocated to the executors.  The raw table on s3, before I put it into a pyspark dataframe is a total of 3MB.  I have not attempted spark 2, and I want to solve this existing problem first.  Does this answer your questions?  why does the sum of the inputs not equal 200MB?

Comment: How do I accurately check the size of my input dataframe for this stage in spark processing?  The way they do it here seems to always return the same result http://metricbrew.com/how-to-estimate-rdd-or-dataframe-real-size-in-pyspark/

Comment: As that link says *if you write out to HDFS or local disc to final size depends on the format you use*. That 200MB on S3 might be compressed in memory...

Comment: Even so.  once I know the data size, what does that tell us?

Comment: I honestly don't know what to tell you. But, let's say your broadcast table is 1MB. If you take `147.3 KB * 4 executors * 2 cores`, you get about 1 MB...

Comment: But I wouldn't expect the broadcast variable to appear in storage memory.  I would expect it to appear in the execution/processing memory.  And that still doesn't explain why it is so slow even when using lots of memory.

Comment: Maybe it's s3 being slow? If your dataset is so small, download it locally. Then, how quickly does it run?

Comment: that 200MB is not on s3.  the 3MB is on s3.  the 200MB is the result of me have the dataframe in a pyspark shell, and then calling the method on the underlying RDD.  So I _imagine_ testing that size would be the same as what it is actually in the JVM when processing

Comment: Sorry, but I'm going to have to ask for a [mcve] of the code. It's hard for me to think of how you've multiplied your input size so much